# Limit of quotient sequence

Tags: limits

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = a$, $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n = +\infty$.

Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\ldots+t_nx_n}{t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n} = a$$

My idea is use that 
$$(t_1+\ldots+t_n)\min\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\leq t_1x_1+\ldots+t_nx_n \leq (t_1+\ldots+t_n)\max\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

But I'm not sure if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\min\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\max\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$.

Comment: Your idea will not work. Take $x_n=(-1)^n/n$. $\min{x_n}=x_{-1}=-1$ and $\max{x_n}=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think $t_n \ge 0$ is esential. Would you be so kind and check the source of you problem?

Answer (score 3):

From your idea, I think you assume that $t_n>0$ when $n$ is large enough.

Then, we can use Stolz Theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\ldots+t_nx_n}{t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t_nx_n}{t_n}. $$

Comment: a requirement for the [Stolz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz_theorem) is that $t_1+...+t_n$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: If $t_n>0$ for $n$ large enough, $t_1+\ldots+t_n$ will increase from some integer $n_0$.

Comment: Of course $t_1+\ldots +t_n$ is increasing if $t_n>0$. I missed that you already assumed $t_n>0$.

Answer (score 2):

For the argument below, we need to assume that $t_n>0$ eventually.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $n_0$ such that $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>n_0$. Then
$$\left|\frac{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\ldots+t_nx_n}{t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n} -a\right|=\left|\frac{t_1(x_1-a)+\cdots +t_n(x_n-a)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\right|\leq\left|\frac{t_1(x_1-a)+\cdots +t_{n_0}(x_{n_0}-a)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\right|+\left|\frac{t_{n_0+1}(x_{n_0+1}-a)+\cdots +t_n(x_n-a)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\right| \\
\leq\left|\frac{t_1(x_1-a)+\cdots +t_{n_0}(x_{n_0}-a)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\right|+
\frac{t_{n_0+1}|x_{n_0+1}-a|+\cdots +t_n|x_n-a|}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\\
\leq\left|\frac{t_1(x_1-a)+\cdots +t_{n_0}(x_{n_0}-a)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\right|+
\varepsilon \,\frac{t_{n_0+1}+\cdots +t_n}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}\\
\leq \frac{(|a|+\max\{|x_n|\})(|t_1|+\cdots+|t_{n_0}|)}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}+\varepsilon.
$$
Taking $\limsup$ we get
$$
\limsup_n\left|\frac{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\ldots+t_nx_n}{t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n} -a\right|
\leq\varepsilon.
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that 
$$
\lim_n\left|\frac{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+\ldots+t_nx_n}{t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_n} -a\right|=0.
$$

Comment: Where is the assumption $t_n \gt 0$ needed?

Comment: I see you assume $t_{n_0+1}=|t_{n_0+1}|, \ldots$

Comment: If you don't have positivity of the $t_n$ (at least eventually) it is conceivable that the ratio $\sum|t_n|/\sum t_n$ is unbounded, and my argument would not work.